# Change Static Table View Cell Height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have an if statement in my app where I want it to change the height of a static tableview cell. Here's what I'm hoping for

```
import UIKit

class DashboardViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell: UITableViewCell!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        // Set cell to "show" on date
        let date = Date()
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date)

        let year =  components.year
        let month = components.month
        let day = components.day

        if(month == 6 && day == 5 && year == 2017) {

          // Here I want the height to be set to 313
        } else {

         // Here I want the height to be set to 0
        }




    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



}
```

The lines that I need help with are marked. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding height constraints to the cell and changing is constant in your condition?

Comment: @AndrezaCristinadaSilva I can't seem to add a height constraint to the cell

Answer (score 0):

You can change the tableview `rowHeight` attribute of your tableview. Using your example:

```
if cell is MyCustomTableViewCell {
   tableView.rowHeight = 313
} else {
    tableView.rowHeight = 0
}
```

Additionally, to effectively change the height of the cell you need to reload the tableview with `tableview.reload()` or refresh the row by its index path:

```
let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowNumber, inSection: 0)
tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)
```

Hopefully this will take you towards the solution you want.

Answer (score 0):

Alrighty here's an edit based on the details you provided in chat.

So first you're going to need to correctly set up your TableViewController. [Here](https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/) is on article I found that covers a lot of table view basics.

**After you set up your table view:**

Your model will need to have some sort of date property in order to match a date condition. Lets say for example your model looks like this:

```
var model = [(text: "here is some text", date: Date())]
```

You'll need to override/implement the function tab `tableView(:_ heightForRowAt indexPath:_)` in your tableViewController/delegate. In this function you'll check for the date coming from the model and apply that to your cell's height.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

   let date = model[indexPath.row].date

   if yourCondition {
      return 313
   } else {
      return = 0
   }
}
```

Comment: If I do this, wouldn't it change all the cells to that?

Comment: @iFunnyVlogger It will check all of the cells, yes. I assure you though this is the correct way to do this. I just may need to modify my answer a bit for you. Let me ask: are you trying to expand the cell on tap or something of that nature? What is the condition where you want to change the cell's height.

Comment: Actually, my if statement is saying that if it is a specific date, the table view cell will be 313, else, it is 0. Here's the code... if(month == 5 && day == 14 && year == 2017) {            
          
        } else {
                
        }

Comment: @iFunnyVlogger Is this specific to the posting date of a cell?

Comment: No, I have let statements declaring what they are. let date = Date() let calendar = Calendar.current | let components = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: date) | let year = components.year | let month = components.month | let day = components.day | and then in my code in my comment, I use these to set the date to June 5, 2017

Comment: @iFunnyVlogger so they're just hard coded values? Would you be willing to edit your question with your complete UITableViewController? It'll make this a lot faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144210/discussion-between-donovan-king-and-ifunnyvlogger).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to change the height of your `UITableViewCell` if particular condition occurred. For such scenario I recommend you to use `UITableView` delegate function i.e. `heightForRowAt indexPath`.

Below is the code snippet:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
if(month == 6 && day == 5 && year == 2017) {
 // Here I want the height to be set to 313
} else {
// Here I want the height to be set to 0
 }
}
```